# Rails Active Record field, dynamic value (evaluation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord

I'm trying to render a JSON object containing a list of Stores (Model: Store). Users have associations to Stores, however each User has a unique # of points available at each store for use. The expression to find the total count of points available for a store is :

```
@user.codes.unspent.find_all_by_store_id(@store.id).count
# unspent is a scope 
# @user is the currently logged in user
# Code model keeps all activity records of points.
```

Because I am rendering a JSON object list of all the Stores, and the above expression is obviously not a field in the Store database, how can I evaluate this expression and return the count for each store?

Also, what are performance implications?

Thanks.

Comment: you should render your own js.erb file

Answer (score 1):

maybe this could help , from [apidocs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)

```
  @events.to_json(:include => {
                    :images => {
                      :only => [], :methods => [:public_url] }})
```

it populate the json with custom method .

Comment: This is on the right track, however I seem to be unable to pass the proper variables to the method I put in the Store model: I did @user = current_user and then called @user in the method, but I'm getting: Nil Class.

Comment: Any ideas? if the custom method is evaluating on individual records, how does scope work?